# Changing the mac address for wlan0 on 17.10?

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

Attempting to change the mac address on Ubuntu 17.10 using macchanger however this is the result:

```
 ole@mki$ sudo macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
 [ERROR] Set device name: No such device
```

Thoughts?

Per the comment I ran `iwconfig` and it turns out that it's `wlo1` now.  Thanks @Jeremy.

Comment: Please edit to add results from terminal for `iwconfig`

Comment: Your wireless interface is likely not wlan0 as `iwconfig` will confirm.

Comment: @Jeremy31 so that was an answer, not a comment.  Please answer, ping me and I'll come back and upvote...  **:-)**

Comment: Indeed - Good answer - I've been used to using ifconfig, but it looks like it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check results for `iwconfig` as wlan0 will not exist by default because of [Predicatable Interface Naming](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) and make necessary adjustments to your macchanger command